# Could not find the correct Provider<BottomNavigationBarBloc> above this BlocBuilder<BottomNavigationBarBloc, BottomNavigationBarState> Widget

Tags: flutter-bloc

Make sure that BlocBuilder<BottomNavigationBarBloc, BottomNavigationBarState> is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

For example, instead of:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<Example>(
    create: (_) => Example(),
    // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
    // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
    child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
  );
}
```

consider using `builder` like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<Example>(
    create: (_) => Example(),
    // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
    builder: (context, child) {
      // No longer throws
      return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
    }
  );
}
```

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return
BlocBuilder<BottomNavigationBarBloc, BottomNavigationBarState>(
builder: (context, state) {
return Scaffold(
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
backgroundColor: ColorManager.white,
selectedItemColor: ColorManager.orangeLight,
unselectedItemColor: ColorManager.grey,
currentIndex: state.index,
onTap: (index){},

```
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
              label: 'Home',
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
              label: 'Shop',
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
              label: 'Bag',
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined),
            label: 'Favorite',
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
              label: 'Profile',
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.person)),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text("hi"),)
 
    );
  },
);
```

}